# How many vertices in the cycle graph $C_n$ have central vertices with minimum distance between any two given vertices(diameter)?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm new to Graph Theory and have come across this question. After much thinking, my best finding is that there are $\frac{n}{2}$ such vertices as for the graph to be a cycle graph every vertex has degree 2. But I'm not sure whether this conclusion is right and how I might be able to give amore formal reasoning of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide you two graphs with the **closed contours (cycles)** as images:

[image]

As you can see in both cases **even** (a) and **odd** (b) closed contours (cycles)
every **vertex** has the degree which is equal to **2**.
$$
diameter(C_n) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{n}{2},&\text{if $n$ is even} \\[2ex]
\frac{n-1}{2},&\text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Let the vertices of the cycle $C_n$ be labeled {1, 2, …n}.

Between any two vertices $i<j$, there is a path of length $j−i$ and of length $n−(j−i)$.

The shorter of these paths can be at most $\frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is **even** and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ if $n$ is **odd**.

Good luck!